# Calculate difference with closest conditioned value in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have the following looking dataframe:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(
    condition = [false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false],
    time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Output:

```
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ condition  time  
     │ Bool       Int64 
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     false      1
   2 │     false      2
   3 │      true      3
   4 │     false      4
   5 │     false      5
   6 │     false      6
   7 │      true      7
   8 │     false      8
   9 │     false      9
  10 │     false     10
```

I would like to calculate the difference in rows with respect to a conditioned value (true/false). This means that for row 1 the nearest true is 2 rows a way. The conditioned rows with true should have a value of 0. Here is the desired output:

```
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ condition  time   diff  
     │ Bool       Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     false      1      2
   2 │     false      2      1
   3 │      true      3      0
   4 │     false      4      1
   5 │     false      5      2
   6 │     false      6      1
   7 │      true      7      0
   8 │     false      8      1
   9 │     false      9      2
  10 │     false     10      3
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to calculate the difference in rows with the closest conditioned value in dataframe Julia?

Comment: This needs a tiny algorithm. Have you tried anything? Also, in time==5, it's not clear if you calculated the difference from the proceeding nearest true or the preceding one.

Comment: Hi @Shayan, for time == 5 both trues are 2 rows away so in this case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transform(df, :condition =>
  (w->((f,u)->min.(f(u),reverse(f(reverse(u)))))(
  v->accumulate(
    (x,y)->ifelse(y,0,x+1),
    v;init=length(v)
  ), 
  w
  )) => :diff)
```

(`u`,`v`,`w` are vectors. `x`,`y` are bool/int. `f` is a function)

Does the job with output:

```
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ condition  time   diff  
     │ Bool       Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     false      1      2
   2 │     false      2      1
   3 │      true      3      0
   4 │     false      4      1
   5 │     false      5      2
   6 │     false      6      1
   7 │      true      7      0
   8 │     false      8      1
   9 │     false      9      2
  10 │     false     10      3
```

On my REPL it was 1-line as follows, but tried to make it more readable above:

```
transform(df, :condition => (v->((f, v)->min.(f(v),reverse(f(reverse(v)))))(v->accumulate((x, y)->ifelse(y, 0, x+1), v; init=length(v)), v)) => :diff)
```

It is not the clearest way, and also not the most efficient, but it is a short piece of code. To get clearer and more efficient result, a separate function should be defined.

Last thing, the column has to have one `true` value, otherwise the results are not meaningful (this can be checked easily with a bit more code, but not sure what OP wants in this case).